# Best practices for android mmo game?

Tags: android, backend

I am planning to make a mmo game like iMobsters from Storm8. There will be no extensive graphics, so i'm particulary interested in whats the best way to build the game backend. SOAP or Rest? Are there any frameworks to build such a backend?

Comment: Whichever enables you to get the game to market: and your personal preference. They are both "web services" and easy of use depends upon libraries/stacks used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @pst's comment: it is personal preference. As I see it, there are two things to consider:

- Ease of development - this is pretty obvious, you want to deliver the product as soon as possible and with the least long-term development cost.
- Performance/bandwidth usage - this is still important for mobile. There are still plenty of mobile carriers with bad data plans, or low-bandwidth services in the world so you can't assume you'll have fast responses or that your users will not care about bandwidth costs.

As @pst said, ease of development comes down to the libraries you're using (both client and server) and no doubt there are good options for both approaches.

As for performance/bandwidth, I would say a RESTful approach probably wins (depending on implementation) due to the fact that there is less overhead. The REST approach is very flexible as it doesn't define any syntax - you're able to use XML, JSON, HTML, or any number of formats for the content.

If I were to implement such a service, I would go with REST for this reason (I guess I'd probably use JSON as it's widely used, easy to parse and lightweight).

As for backend frameworks, I couldn't really say without knowing what technology you'll be using on the server - are you running on Java, .NET, Perl, etc? Regardless, there are abundant resources for any of the major server-side technologies for serving up either RESTful or SOAP-based APIs.